# Custom number format in Excel

Tags: excel, formats

Not sure if possible, haven't been able to figure anything out myself so trying here.

I want to type in 4 numbers into a cell, but have them formatted like this:

```
1012 -> 1 / 0 / 1 / 2
```

I know I could do this by typing it into another cell and reading the nth value from it, but I'd like to avoid that since it will be confusing for the person entering the data.

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there will always be 4 digits then you can use a custom format like this

`0"/"0"/"0"/"0`

To apply that, select cell range then right-click > Format cells > Number > Custom and type the above in the box provided > OK

Answer (score 2):

Do Format Cells > Number > Custom and enter:

```
0" / "0" / "0" / "0
```

[image]